# ¿Porque el programa me devuelve : "Estoy teniendo pensamientos felices"?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, codeblocks

Estaba programando en c++ y me resulto extraño que cuando no haya dado un valor determinado para las variables estas cumplan una condición de ser mayores a 100, en este caso son las variables enteras SocialLevel y Luck, dejo mi código por si alguien puede ayudarme.

El problema esta justo donde se evalúan las funciones en if(SocialLevel + Luck >100), resulta que esta se cumple y se ejecuta el cout, pero no se si se le asignan valores de la memoria que se encontraban en la memoria antes de darles el valor o porque se cumple el if.

Ya ejecute varias veces el programa pero siempre me da el mismo resultado.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Human
{
 public:
 Human(int SpawnAge)
  {
    Age = SpawnAge;
  }
  int Age;

  void Think()
  {
    cout << GetThinkingMessage() << endl;
  }

  private:

  int SocialLevel;
  int Inteligence;
  int Luck;

  string GetThinkingMessage()
  {
    if(SocialLevel + Luck > 100)
    {
        return "Estoy teniendo pensamientos felices";
    }
    else if(Luck > Inteligence)
    {
        return "Soy un suertudo";
    }
    else if(Age > 18)
    {
        return "Soy un bb";
    }
    else
    {
        return "no pienso nada";
    }
  }
};


  int main()
  {
  Human Bob(19);

  Bob.Think();

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Efectivamente puede que exista informacion en los segmentos de memoria que has declarado, prueba a inizializar las variables del humano en 0 para testearlo, para esto puedes usar un constructor -> http://conclase.net/c/curso/cap29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las variables no se inicializan a no ser que se pida hacerlo explícitamente. Si no pides inicializar una variable, esta obtendrá un valor residual.

Un entero (`int`) tiene dos mil ciento cuarenta y siete millones cuatrocientos ochenta y tres mil seiscientos cuarenta y ocho valores positivos y cualquiera de estos valores puede aparecer en una variable sin inicializar. La gran mayoría de esos valores serán mayores a cien.

Inicializa tus variables y el "*problema*" desaparecerá, puedes usar cualquiera de estas inicializaciones:

- Inicialización por defecto: las variables enteras se inicializan a cero:

  ```
  int SocialLevel{};
  int Inteligence{};
  int Luck{};
  ```

- Inicialización explícita: das un valor explícito a las variables:

  ```
  int SocialLevel = 0;
  int Inteligence = 0;
  int Luck = 0;
  ```